# Plot shape with it's control net

Tags: blender

In "Ming-Jun Lai, Larry L. Schumaker. Spline Functions on Triangulations. Cambridge University Press, 2007, p.64", the author plotted a surface and it's corresponded control net:
[image]

For my thesis, i need to plot the same thing. How can i plot an object like this? A shape with it's control net and control point. My platform is GNU/Linux 3.13. I can use python, blender or Matlab.